# Using PHP's date functionality to determine date submission order and offset

Tags: php, date, sequence

If I have a series of dates in the following format (`YYYY-mm-dd`) , how can I determine using PHP's date functionality that each date is at least 24 hours after the previous one and the dates are sequential.

For instance:

1. 2010-11-01
2. 2010-11-01
3. 2010-11-02

Would fail because 2 isn't 24 hours after 1.

Or for example:

1. 2010-10-15
2. 2010-11-01
3. 2010-11-02

Would fail because 1 is earlier than 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dates = array('2010-11-03', '2010-11-01', '2010-11-07');
var_dump(validDates($dates)); // bool(false)

$dates = array('2010-11-01', '2010-11-03', '2010-11-07');
var_dump(validDates($dates)); // bool(true)

function validDates($dates) {
    $lastDate = NULL;
    foreach($dates as $date) {
        $date = strtotime($date);
        if ($date < $lastDate + (24 * 3600)) {
            return FALSE;
        }
        $lastDate = $date;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

[See it.](http://codepad.org/X2yQzwos)